# How can I change canvas globalAlpha as ctx moves along the X-axis

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I have made an audio-player and it has a canvas for its seeklider.
The ctx is the pointer that tracks audio.currentTime.
I am trying to achieve an effect so that when the ctx is moving along the X axis, the canvas before that point should have globalAlpha set to 0.4, and canvas after the ctx set to globalAlpha = 0.6.

```
<div class="slider-container ">
        <canvas id ="canvas" height ="90" width ="300"></canvas>
    </div>
    
//Javascript
//Load canvasbackground image.
 function drawbg(){
     canvasbackground_index = playlist_index;
     canvasbg.src = cdir+canvasbackground[canvasbackground_index]+png;
     ctx.drawImage(canvasbg,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }
//calculate canvas.ctx position on X-axis relative to audio.currentTime
function ctxupdate() {
    ct = audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration);
     ctx.x = (ct/100) * canvas.width;
     seekto = ctx.x;
    }
//draw a thin vertical rectangle relative to audio.currentTime
function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250,250,250)";
    ctx.fillRect(ctx.x, 0, 1, 90);
    ctx.x = ct;
  }
//animate canvas
  function canvasAnimate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(canvasAnimate);
    drawbg();
    ctxupdate();
    draw();
  }
canvasAnimate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using js instead of css be ok. Something similar to this?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 100;

let pic = new Image();
pic.src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/72975551.cms"

class Cursor {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x ,0, 2, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  update() {
    this.x == canvas.width ? this.x = 0 : this.x++
    this.draw();
  }
}
let cursor = new Cursor(0);

function changeBG() {
  ctx.drawImage(pic,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 0 + cursor.x, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cursor.x + canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function animate() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   cursor.update();
   changeBG();
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id ="canvas" height ="90" width ="300"></canvas>
```

UPDATE: I took your `ctxupdate()` function and moved the contents of that to `drawbg()`. Then I added the `fillRect` and `fillStyle` code from above to `drawbg()`. The `stopCanvasbg()` is not used but I left it because you had it in there.

So from your `sizeCanvas()` to your `canvasAnimate()` here;s what it looks like

```
function sizecanvas() {
    if(window.innerWidth >= 1469) { 
        canvas.width = 1469 
        canvas.clientWidth = canvas.width;
    } else {
        canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    }
  }

  function drawbg(){
    ct = audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration);
    //if (isNaN(ctx.x)) return;
    ctx.x = (ct/100) * canvas.width;
    seekto = ctx.x;
    canvasbackground_index = playlist_index;
    canvasbg.src = cdir+canvasbackground[canvasbackground_index]+png;
    ctx.drawImage(canvasbg,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 0 + seekto, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, seekto + canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

function stopCanvasbg(){
    canvasbackground_index = (canvasbackground.length -1);
      console.log(canvasbackground_index);
      canvasbg.src = canvasbackground_index;
      ctx.drawImage(canvasbg,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function canvasAnimate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawbg();
  requestAnimationFrame(canvasAnimate);
}
canvasAnimate();
```

See if that works on your end.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was after, I'm trying to apply it to my code right now.

Comment: I tried to adapt it to fit in my code, not working right now and im too tired to continue.
Thanks a lot for the code snippet. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Did you get it working? I updated it to have different opacity on each side of the cursor. I would need a working portion of you code in order to help put it into yours.

Comment: WoW thanks man!! Ive seen building this thing for a year now! The HTML for the audio player is 28 lines and the JS for it is about 445 lines. or I can send the whole thing as a zip?

Comment: GitHub would be the best way. Just post it there and link your account here so I can go download it.

Comment: https://github.com/MoHowler/Muzika-canvas-prototype
I would need to invite you to see the code.
Pretty new to GitHub...

Comment: Sure user name jfirestorm44

Comment: Haven't seen anything but the license. Did you upload the files?

Comment: my bad, me being a noob, uploading files now.

Comment: files uploaded.

Comment: Nice one, hey thanks a bunch man, I just put it in my code and its working beautifully.

Comment: the stopCanvasbg() was meant to load a black image so to have a blank canvas when 'stop' is activated, but the canvasAnimate() overrides it. So yea, useless function.

Comment: Great! Don’t forget to hit that answer button.

Comment: Hello, I don't know what you mean by 'hit that answer button'. I don't have enough reputation points to up vote but I want to give you your points. The only button I see is 'Answer Your Question' button.